# predicate logic - function mapping outside of domain

Tags: predicate-logic

Can a model of a sentence in predicate logic contain a function that can map to a member not contained in the domain of that model?

Example. Is this interpretation correct : domain= $\{1,2\}$ ; sentence=$'(∃x)(∃y)(P(f(xy)))'$ ; $f(xy) =$ the the product of $x$ and $y$ ; $P(x)=x$ is positive. The sentence seems true, but on an assignment $(x=2$ and $y=2)$, the function maps to $4$, which is not contained in the domain.

**EDIT** : Second question : How would we qualify this model? True, false, neither of those?

Comment: Not a model.  The interpretation of $f$ must be a dyadic function from the domain to itself.

Comment: Additionally Your statement, at the start is not valid because we know nothing about the domain of $y$, so when you write $'(∃x)(P(f(xy)))'$, we assume there exists an x in D.  By y remains a free variable.

Comment: You are right, I will edit.

Comment: Note that indeed, $$\exists x\exists y(P(xy))$$  Take $x=1, y=1$, e.g., you need only prove here that indeed, there is such a pair $x, x \in D$ such that $xy>0$ is true.  Now perhaps you mean to define $f(x, y) = xy$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is No; interpretations of function symbols must be functions that map objects from the domain to the domain, so you can't map to anything outside the domain.

Also, your sentence should be $\exists x \exists y P(f(x,y))$